# Is it better to do this conversion job using Queue or Schedule?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to convert/resize uploaded images using Laravel so they are available during the next seconds or minute or so...

I was wondering, to have less pressure on the server, is it better to do this using Laravel `Schedules` or `Queues`

If `Queues` is the way to go, how to dispatch? (delayed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting multiple users uploading multiple images concurrently, in that case,  I would stick with `Queue` for this task. Here's a link to [Laravel 7.x Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#creating-jobs), they have really good documentation.

**Step 1**: `php artisan queue:table` & `php artisan migrate`. This will create 2 tables: *jobs* and *failed_jobs*.

**Step 2**: Create a Job `php artisan make:job ResizeImage`. This will create a new file under *jobs* folder. It's the `implements ShouldQueue` that's gonna do the magic for you.

**Step 3**: To make a [dispatch call](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#dispatching-jobs).  `ResizeImage::dispatch($params);`. To delay, add `->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));`

**Step 4**: In your .env file, change `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` to `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`. This config will be used by `config/queue.php` file.

**Step 5**: Clear config and cache. `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan cache:clear`

Things to understand:

- When you dispatch a job, a new row will be added to *jobs* table. Whatever you add to the handle() method in your jobs file will be added to the *payload* column of the table.
- To trigger the queue, you can either add a `supervisor` to your server or a simple `php artisan queue:work` will run the jobs.

Please go through the docs, they have really good + deep + better explanation with examples. Cheers!